# What can be the reason for "Invalid module format"?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-panic, kernel-modules

I'm following the steps to compile kernel 2.6.32 from source,

and have no problem to go the the last step:

```
...
make modules_install 
make install
```

And I've also configured `grub.conf` correctly.

But when I try to `reboot`,it fails to boot:

```
insmod: error insertimg '/lib/ehci-hcd.ko': -1 Invalid module format
...
```

What can be the reason?

[image: Error when booting]

Answer (score 2):

Module and kernel are not the same version OR, some times, you can get this error if you didn't used the same compiler for modules and kernel.

In your case, you recompiled the kernel and you didn't change/rebuild initrd. The screenshot what you posted now, show us a bad initrd with old modules. You should reboot with the old kernel (if you didn't overwrite it) and rebuild initrd also.

Regards

Comment: All those are reported "Invalid module format" are kernel modules..

Comment: You forget to rebuild initrd.

Comment: Nope,`make install` does this for you automatically.

Comment: OK, then you forgot to add it to command line.

Answer (score 0):

Check `dmesg`, there should be a better message which states why the loading failed.

Comment: But when kernel panic happens,I can not type any shell commands.